# Определить на каком месте в алфавите выбранный символ

Tags: php

Input: ВАЗ
Out: 319

Не обязательно возвращать так, можно по коду символу ascii
Входная строка может быть как на латинице так и на кириллице, учесть, что "А" и "а" разные символы и "место" у них будет разное

```
$key = 'VAZ';
$length = count($key); //длина ключа
for ($i=0; $i <$length ; $i++) { 
    echo ord($key[$i]). ' | ';
}
```

на латинице всё норм, выводит код символа как надо, а вот на кириллице нет, показывает либо 209, либо 208 на всех символах русских

когда делаю echo на $key, то там кракозябры, как вылечить?

Comment: А `php` знает что котировка ваших символов `UTF-8`?

Comment: Можно код вашей функции `ord()` увидеть?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, ord() стандартная функция PHP.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan скорее всего нет:) как указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа этого. Пишу на коленке так что, возможно есть более элегантное решение.

```html
$key = 'VAZ';
$offset_lower = 123; // нужно указать правильное значение начала позиции по таблице ASCII
$offset_upper = 345; // нужно указать правильное значение начала позиции по таблице ASCII
$length = count($key); //длина ключа
for ($i=0; $i <$length ; $i++) { 
    echo (ord($key[$i]) - (mb_strtoupper($key[$i]) === $key[$i] ? $offset_upper : $offset_lower)). ' | ';
}
```

Comment: буква Ё вам всю логику испортит)

Comment: @ar3409, это уже другая проблема. :)